# How to 'pip install uwsgi' with alternative build configuration?

Tags: python, pip, uwsgi

I'm trying to install [uWSGI](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) with pip for deploying a Django project:

```
$ pip install uwsgi
[...]
################# uWSGI configuration #################

pcre = False
kernel = Linux
malloc = libc
execinfo = False
ifaddrs = True
ssl = True
zlib = True
locking = pthread_mutex
plugin_dir = .
timer = timerfd
yaml = embedded
json = False
filemonitor = inotify
routing = False
debug = False
capabilities = False
xml = expat
event = epoll

############## end of uWSGI configuration #############
[...]
```

I see the build configuration there being shown with some options I'd like to change.

- `ssl` (done in nginx, I don't want the `uwsgi` binary to link to OpenSSL)
- For a development machine I'd like to enable `routing` and `pcre` to quickly set up the embedded HTTP server.

How do I do that with `pip install uwsgi`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The setup process checks an environment variable `UWSGI_PROFILE_OVERRIDE` which can override these configurations. It consists of `key=value` pairs separated by `;` (semicolons). The values `true` and `false` must be lowercase which tripped me up at first.

So you could try `UWSGI_PROFILE_OVERRIDE=ssl=false;routing=true;pcre=true`

However, there's a bunch of auto-detection of capabilities happening too, so it might be that it complains about libraries when you try to force options on.

Comment: Interesting. It appears to be [undocumented](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/search.html?q=UWSGI_PROFILE_OVERRIDE&check_keywords=yes&area=default). How did you find this?

Comment: Source diving. It does seem to be left out of the otherwise extensive docs.

Comment: 4 years later, still undocumented, but is effective